# Writing R Extension Using #include<igraph>

Tags: c, r, igraph

I have been able to write simple R extensions in C by doing the following:

- writing a C function
- compiling it using R CMD SHLIB "function name.c"
- using dyn.load("functionname.so") in R

Now, I have written some more advanced C functions that use the igraph library.  However, the compiling command above (R CMD SHLIB) does not recognize `#include<igraph.h>`.  Is there a way to adapt the R CMD SHLIB command so that it will find the igraph library?  When I compile my C code regularly, I use the following compile command to include igraph:

```
gcc -I MY_IGRAPH_DIR/install/include/igraph -L MY_IGRAPH_DIR/install/lib myfunction.c -o myfunction
```

I realize that to pass more than just an integer vector to C I will want to explore sexp and .Call.  Currently, I am just trying to get small functions to work so that I have a place to start.  Also, I prefer C and am trying to avoid RCPP.

Comment: The conventional way to spell that `#include` directive would be `#include <igraph.h>` -- note the ".h".  That may or may not be related to the issue.

Comment: That was an error in my question, not my code.  Fixed!  Thanks.

Comment: I strongly advise you to build a package instead. Then you could link to igraph and use its header files. See Writing R Extensions for details.

Comment: As an update to this post, I did opt to build a package.  The learning curve was steep in the beginning, but now that everything is setup, adding functions to the package (and editing the functions) is a breeze.  Thanks!